# How to use hooks in child theme to override a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add some HTML code to a **plugin** but I want to do that in a **child theme**, the function that I wanna override it is in a file named as admin-functions.php

I want to add extra **buttons** to **booked_render_custom_fields** function

admin-functions.php:

```
 function booked_render_custom_fields($calendar = false) { ?>
    <button class="button">Text</button>;
<?php }
```

any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can't really override a function like that. you can only use the filters and hooks that the plugin implements. but you got some options:

a) make a copy of the plugin, change it's name and make the changes you need. after that, it wont get updates anymore. you'll have to implement them manually.

b) you could add just one line to the original plugin and define a filter or hook to which you subscribe in your functions.php . so you only have to fix this one line after updating the plugin.

c) since the newer versions of wordpress, you have the possibilites to run your own code after any shortcode. so you could add or inject your own html into the output of the shortcode. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/